# Toggle LoggedInTemplate after registration approved

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have an ASP.NET Web Form application that is using the default ASP.NET MembershipProvider.

After registration, I require the administrator to approve the registration. Until that occurs, I would like the AnonymousTemplate in the LoginView to be shown.

The site uses the default code for the Site.Master.

My question is, can I modify the default behavior of the LoginView control so that it shows the LoggedInTemplate only after a registered user is approved by an administrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MembershipUser object should have flags for IsActive and IsApproved. If you set both to false during the registration process, and do not log the user in after they are registered, then the template should stay anonymous. Then your Admin UI will have to set those flags to true, then save the user through the Membership API, then send them an e-mail that they are approved and can log in.

HTH

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try tomorrow.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. The default Registration form adds a Registered cookie, and that left them thinking they had been approved.